# What is our confidence with respect to the critical density of the universe?

Tags: space-expansion, dark-matter, dark-energy

How can scientists speak confidently about the critical density of the universe while knowing the majority of matter and energy is foreign and not well understood. Shouldn't more knowledge about dark matter and energy first precede any conclusions we draw about the metrics which determine the universes expansion?

Comment: Your question is ill-defined. There is a small uncertainty in the value of the present day critical density, but what of it? The expansion is observable, as is its history.

Comment: I don't know what critical density refers to, but the question is a valid one. Specially when you hear about dark matter in non-specialized media, as we do every day, without clear definition of what it is. @efreezy dark matter might not mean there is unobserved matter. Larger gravitational effect is observed in further celestial systems, which is interpreted as matter existing there, but non reacting with light like normal matter. However this interpretation, although the most accepted in the community, is not ruled out completely other interpretations. This is still open topic.

Answer (score 1):

The critical density is an observable quantity.
$$\rho_C = \frac{3H_0^2}{8\pi G},$$
where $H_0$ is the present-day value of the Hubble parameter.

$H_0$ is known (observationally) from a variety of methods to be 69 km/s per Mpc, with an accuracy of about 1 per cent.

So to answer your question as posed, the critical density has a confidence interval of about $\pm 2$ per cent.

What determines the expansion rate of the universe is not the critical density, which is *defined* in terms of the present expansion rate, but what the ratio is to $\rho_C$ of the various forms of matter and energy density that make up the universe.